# XenServer Java remote access

Tags: java, remote-access, citrix

I have a open source xenserver product (from xenserver.org).
I need to remote acces to VM from Java code. For example, to remotely reboot.
I found SDK "Get Started with API" http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.2.0/1.0/en_gb/sdk.html , but I don't understand how to connect to a remote server. Which IP should be in the code?:

```
Connection connection = new Connection(new URL("https://what_ip?"));
System.out.println(connection.getAPIVersion());
System.out.println(connection.getSessionReference());
```

Comment: if your vm are running on vsphere than use vijava.jar [open source] or vim.jar [provided by vmware]. Awesome API to connect with vsphere vm and perform multiple operations on machines. You might required lot of struggle in initial if you not aware about vsphere environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i don't use the vsphere. I use citrix xen ( http://www.xenserver.org/ )

Answer (score 2):

You need only the IP of the Xenserver hypervisor. You don't need any port to establish connection.

You can use this code to establish a connection with your xenserver hypervisor.

```
    import com.xensource.xenapi.APIVersion;
    import com.xensource.xenapi.Connection;
    import com.xensource.xenapi.Session;
    try{
        Connectionn conn = new Connection(new URL(xenservIP));
        Session.loginWithPassword(conn, xenservUsername,xenservPassword, APIVersion.latest().toString());
} catch(BadServerResponse | SessionAuthenticationFailed | XenAPIException | XmlRpcException | MalformedURLException) {// Your code}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without to read the xenserver documentation, I would tell you, that you need to use your public IP or subdomain that xenserver.org gives to you. And you need to create a session with you authentications params: user/password. This forum could help you:

http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/349096-xenserver-java-remote-access/

Comment: ip or subdomain, which gives me xenserver.org? That is, the server that is running xenserver? Yes, I use this IP. But that should handle the connection on the side xenserver? What port should I use?

Comment: I have added a link to the response, you don't need a port, but you need to authenticate in the way that they write in the code. And you need to use the right IP (the master).